# Creating a dictionary from CSV data

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

I have a function that takes a CSV file and splits it into 3 values; `isbn`, `author` and `title` then creates a dictionary that maps `isbn` values to tuples containing the `author` and `title`. This is my current code:

```
def isbn_dictionary(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in file:
        data = line.strip('\n')
        author, title, isbn = data.split(',') 
        isbn_dict = {isbn:(author, title)}
        print(isbn_dict)
```

The problem is that at the moment I can get it to create a dictionary for each `isbn` but not one for all of them. My current output is:

```
{'0-586-08997-7': ('Kurt Vonnegut', 'Breakfast of Champions')}
{'978-0-14-302089-9': ('Lloyd Jones', 'Mister Pip')}
{'1-877270-02-4': ('Joe Bennett', 'So Help me Dog')}
{'0-812-55075-7': ('Orson Scott Card', 'Speaker for the Dead')}
```

What my output should be:

```
{'0-586-08997-7': ('Kurt Vonnegut', 'Breakfast of Champions'),
'978-0-14-302089-9': ('Lloyd Jones', 'Mister Pip'),
'1-877270-02-4': ('Joe Bennett', 'So Help me Dog'),
'0-812-55075-7': ('Orson Scott Card', 'Speaker for the Dead')}
```

It's probably a really simple issue but I cannot get my head around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `isbn_dict` before the loop, like this:

```
def isbn_dictionary(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    isbn_dict = {}
    for line in file:
        data = line.strip('\n')
        author, title, isbn = data.split(',') 
        isbn_dict[isbn] = (author, title)
    print(isbn_dict)
```

This way, each item is added to the existing dictionary.

Comment: Like the OP, you don't actually *return* the resulting dictionary. Printing is a nice debug tool, but doesn't make the function very useful.

Comment: @AlcariTheMad Also you should `close` the file

Comment: @AlcariTheMad Thanks for your answer, I knew it would be relatively simple.

Comment: It's better to use `with open(...) as localname:`, that way the file is closed automatically when the `with` block ends.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I made the minimal changes required to make the function produce the correct dictionary. I don't generally use py3, so dict comprehensions aren't something I think of immediately.

Comment: @AlcariTheMad: For what it's worth, dict comprehensions work in Python 2.7 too. :-) My answer would work with minimal changes in that version (replace `newline=''` with `'rb'`).

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for easier and more efficient processing, and a dict comprehension:

```
import csv

def isbn_dictionary(filename):
    with open(filename, newline='') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        return {isbn: (author, title) for isbn, author, title in reader}
```

Your code only created a dictionary *per line* and only printed the dictionary. You probably wanted to *return* the dictionary instead.

Using a dict comprehension not only makes the function more compact, it is also more efficient. The dictionary is created in one go, in C code, instead of in a Python loop adding keys and values one by one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have noticed that in my code, I actually should be returning and not printing.

Comment: Although @AlcariTheMad fixes the bug in OP's code, this is the most Pythonic answer