# How to create a dictionary from CSV using a loop function?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I am trying to create several dictionaries out of a table of comments from a CSV with the following columns:
[image: Table of Comments]

I need to create a dictionary for every row (hopefully using a loop so I don't have to create them all manually), where the dictionary keys are:

- ID
- ReviewType
- Comment

However, I cannot figure out a fast way to do this. I tried creating a list of dictionaries using the following code:

```
# Import libraries
import csv
import json
import pprint

# Open file
reader = csv.DictReader(open('Comments.csv', 'rU'))

# Create list of dictionaries
dict_list = []
for line in reader:
    dict_list.append(line)

pprint.pprint(dict_list)
```

However, now I do not know how to access the dictionaries or whether the key value pairs are matched properly since in the following image:

- The ID, ReviewType and Comment do not seem to be showing as
  dictionary keys
- The Comment value seems to be showing as a list of half-sentences.

[image: Result]

Is there any way to just create one dictionary for each row instead of a list of dictionaries?

**Note: I did look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582916/creating-a-dictionary-from-csv-data) question, however it didn't really help.**

Comment: The way you specify your question, you seem to be expecting some kind of sparse input, otherwise you would probably be better off using a list, wouldn't you?

Comment: Plus, I don't see what would be the (unique) key to the dictionary. Assuming that you have three different dictionaries, how would you want to access each of them? Simply by ID?

Comment: you get an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict) as result. you can just access it the way you would a normal `dict`. (or you create a `dict` from it - if you prefer.) the comments are fine; `pprint` just puts them on multiple lines.

Comment: The purpose of using a dictionary is because I want to show a count of words later using NLTK. The unique key to the dictionary would be the ID.

Comment: So why wouldn't you simply use a list? You can also use the ID as a key, but save yourself the trouble of creating a dictionary, which is also more costly for such operations.

Comment: Because I want to show the distribution of words as a count, not simply count the number of words for each row in the CSV.

Comment: @drmyrnz Does my solution work?

Comment: Thanks @hiroprotagonist, I will try to use that solution first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. I put the comment into an array

```
# Import libraries
import csv
import json
import pprint

# Open file


def readPerfReviewCSVToDict(csvPath):
    reader = csv.DictReader(open(csvPath, 'rU'))

    perfReviewsDictionary = []
    for line in reader:
        perfReviewsDictionary.append(line)

    perfReviewsDictionaryWithCommentsSplit = []
    for item in perfReviewsDictionary:
        itemId = item["id"]
        itemType = item["type"]
        itemComment = item["comments"]
        itemCommentDictionary = []
        itemCommentDictionary = itemComment.split()
        perfReviewsDictionaryWithCommentsSplit.append({'id':itemId, 'type':itemType, 'comments':itemCommentDictionary})

    return perfReviewsDictionaryWithCommentsSplit

dict_list = readPerfReviewCSVToDict("test.csv")
pprint.pprint(dict_list)
```

The output is:

```
[{'comments': ['test', 'ape', 'dog'], 'id': '1', 'type': 'Test'},
 {'comments': ['dog'], 'id': '2', 'type': 'Test'}]
```

Comment: No problem - glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't given a reproducible example, with a sample DataFrame, I've created one for you

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "Contractor", "Please post"], [2, "Developer", "a reproducible example"]])
df.columns = ['ID', 'ReviewType', 'Comment']
```

In your computer, instead of doing this, type:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

to read in the csv file as a pandas DataFrame.

Now I will create a list, called `dictList` which will be empty initially, I am going to populate it with a dictionary for each row in the DataFrame `df`

```
dictList = []

#Iterate over each row in df
for i in df.index:

    #Creating an empty dictionary for each row
    rowDict = {}

    #Populating it
    rowDict['ID'] = df.at[i, 'ID']
    rowDict['ReviewType'] = df.at[i, 'ReviewType']
    rowDict['Comment'] = df.at[i, 'Comment']

    #Once I'm done populating it, I will append it to the list
    dictList.append(rowDict)

    #Go to the next row and repeat.
```

Now iterating over the list of dictionaries we have created for my example

```
for i in dictList:
    print(i)
```

We get

```
{'ID': 1, 'ReviewType': 'Contractor', 'Comment': 'Please post'}
{'ID': 2, 'ReviewType': 'Developer', 'Comment': 'a reproducible example'}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I really like that you explained everything as well, however I'm trying to avoid using lists as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
DICT = {}
for line in reader:
    DICT[line['ID']] = line
```